# Working of Sort Algorithm in C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

From the usage of Sort(begin,end) it appears that by just specifying the containers beginning and ending index the function can sort a container. But my question how does the sort function gets the type of containers.

```
std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
```

From the above code I assume the starting and end index is send. How come the vector type and the vector name is deduced.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't care about the type of container - only the type of iterators.  It requires RandomAccessIterators, which is why you cannot use `std::sort` with a `std::list`

Answer (score 7):

The function [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), like many others from `<algorithm>`, does not care about the container type because it works with *concepts*.

Specifically, the function is defined as:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```

As you can see, templates are used to express the concept of [`ValueSwappable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable) and [`RandomAccessIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) iterators.

Comment: Sorry Could not understand could you please elaborate a little more

Comment: Also if it doesn't care about the container type how can a sort function compare values.

Comment: @krish_oza, read about templates and then the links I've added in my answer. Everything will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

myvector.begin()/end() returns type "containertype::iterator"

As to how the sort() works, it actually doesn't care about the underlying container type, as long as the two elements in the container are comparable (either `less<type>()` exist for that element, or you specify your own comparing function).

Comment: The "comparable" requirement is definitely not the only one.

Comment: @Jefffrey What else? iterator being RandomAccessIterator / two iterators within the same container?

Comment: Take a look at the links in my answer (specifically the `ValueSwappable` and `RandomAccessIterator` requirements.